# Selectr plugin is not working with multiple select instances?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a selectbox JS plugin to style selectoboxes.
it seems the plugin is not initilizing when there are multiple selectboxes instances on a page.

**Selectr plugin:**
https://github.com/Mobius1/Selectr

**demo:**
https://jsbin.com/haxamipizo/edit?html,js,output

this is how I'm initializing the plugin as per the docs:

```
new Selectr('.selecting');
```

what am I missing? is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library you use uses [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) when passing in a selector string.

> https://github.com/Mobius1/Selectr/blob/master/src/selectr.js#L963
>
> ```
> var Selectr = function(el, config) {
>     //....
>     this.el = el;
>
>     // CSS3 selector string
>     if (typeof el === "string") {
>         this.el = document.querySelector(el);
>     }
> ```

That means it is only going to grab the first element that matches. In order to get all your elements initiated you will have to loop through them yourself calling `new Selectr()` on each.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.selecting').forEach(element=>{
  new Selectr(element);  
});
```

Demo

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.selecting').forEach(element => {
  new Selectr(element);
});
```

```html
<select class="selecting">
 <option vlaue="value-1">Value 1</option>
 <option vlaue="value-2">Value 2</option>
 <option vlaue="value-3">Value 3</option>
 ...
</select>

<div class="divider">

  <select class="selecting">
 <option vlaue="value-1">Value 4</option>
 <option vlaue="value-2">Value 5</option>
 <option vlaue="value-3">Value 6</option>
 ...
</select>


  <div class="divider">

    <select class="selecting">
 <option vlaue="value-1">Value 6</option>
 <option vlaue="value-2">Value 7</option>
 <option vlaue="value-3">Value 8</option>
 ...
</select>



    <link href="https://unpkg.com/mobius1-selectr@latest/dist/selectr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mobius1-selectr@latest/dist/selectr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *You can then instantiate Selectr by passing a reference to your select box as the first parameter... (from Selectr github)*

Looks like it will work for you if you will use Selectr object for each select tag, not for a collection.

So, change your class names to id's in your html, and create multiple Selectr objects.

```
new Selectr('#selecting1');
new Selectr('#selecting2');
new Selectr('#selecting3');
```